# Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". When saving files on the same folder on my computer

Tags: javascript, null, same-origin-policy

Hello I'm currently working on a popup excercise where two windows would exhcange some text with each other. 
The main page is as follows

Name: ch08_examp5.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chapter 8: example 5</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var newWindow;
      function btnOpenWin_onclick() {
        newWindow = window.open("ch08_examp5_popup.htm", "myWindow");
      }
      function btnGetText_onclick() {
        if (typeof (newWindow) == "undefined" || newWindow.closed == true ) {
          alert ("No window is opened");
        }
        else {
          document.form1.text1.value = newWindow.document.form1.text1.value;
        }
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form  action="" name="form1" method="post">
      <input type="button" name="btnOpenWin" value="Open newWindow"
      onclick="btnOpenWin_onclick()" />
      <p>
      newWindow's Text:<br />
      <input type="text" name="text1" />
      <input type="button" value="Get Text" name="btnGetText"
      onclick="btnGetText_onclick()" />
      </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the second page is

Name: ch08_examp5_popup.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chapter 8: example 5 popup exmaple</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function btnGetText_onclick() {
        document.form1.text1.value = window.opener.document.form1.text1.value;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onunload="window_onunload()">
    <form  action="" name="form1" method="post">
      Opener window's text <br>
      <input type="text" name="text1" >
      <input type="button" name="btnGetText" value="Get Text"
        onclick="btnGetText_onclick()" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The error message I receive is "Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match." which is weird because I have them saved on my computer on the same folders.

thanks for the help!